# How can i create a template for the user to fill in, after they click on a button on top of an image?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, viewmodel

This type - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg and the image is the button or has a button on top of it and then
I want to redirect the user to a template to fill in

- https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/images/forms/styled_contact_form.png
  something of this type.
  Do I need JavaScript for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a modal,here is a demo:

```
<input data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" type="image" src="~/images/button1.jpg" />
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Contact Us</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ... your content here
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: can you help me with the MVC set up for that,especially the view

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an href tag or you can make modal pop up when the user clicks on the image. (the second option requires js) but seems like what you need is a simple link to another page with a form on it.

for the modal, check out w3bschools.com for the modal tutorial.